# Remove duplicates lines without keeping one

Tags: python, text

How can I remove duplicates lines without keeping one like that:

> blabla
>   potato
>   blabla

to:

> potato

Comment: Which programming language do you want to achieve this in?

Comment: No matter but I prefer python

Comment: This means that your question is #1 - too broad and #2 - prone to opinion-based answers (whichever favorite language people have). Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from StackOverflow documentation. I will add a Python tag so you can get a decent answer.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you struggling SO isn't a code writing service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how often the lines appear, then filter for lines that appear only once.

```
>>> lines="""blabla
... potato
... blabla""".splitlines()
>>> counts = collections.Counter(lines)
>>> [line for line in lines if counts[line] == 1]
['potato']
```

This is faster than using `lines.count` for each line, although this should barely matter unless the number of lines is *very* high.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lines = ["blabla", "potato", "blabla"]

final_lines = [i for i in lines if lines.count(i) == 1]
```